# Call a function while the phone is being shaken

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5

I'm making an app that uses motionBegan to call a function.
However it just call my function once when I shake my phone, then once more if I stop and shake it again.
While I want to have the func active as long as I'm shaking the phone.
Any ideas what I should do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Swift:**

```
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if motion == .motionShake {
            print("Device Shaked")
        }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {        
        NSLog(@"Device Shaked") ;
    }
}
```